# JOOQ insert if condition is met

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have a table called `TimeTracks`:

```
CREATE TABLE "TimeTracks" (
    "id" uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    "startTime" timestamp(3) NOT NULL,
    "endTime" timestamp(3),
    "taskId" uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES "Tasks"("id"),
    UNIQUE ("taskId", "endTime")
);
```

When inserting the time tracks the following condition must be met:

*The timespan between `startTime` and `endTime` of time tracks with the same `taskId` may not overlap.*

When using raw SQL people suggest doing something like that:

```
insert into TimeTrack (id, startTime, endTime, taskId)
select
    'some Id', 'some startTime', 'some endTime', 'some taskId'
where not exists (
    select * from TimeTrack where
    (('some startTime' between startTime and endTime)
    or ('some endTime' between startTime and endTime))
    and ('some taskId' == taskId)
);
```

**How can I do the same thing (or something with the equivalent outcome) in JOOQ?**

(I am using PostgreSQL)

Comment: I would suggest you add a trigger for this kind of integrity check...

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) I´m going to try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This translates directly to jOOQ SQL:

```java
Timetracks t = TIMETRACKS;

ctx.insertInto(t)
   .columns(t.ID, t.STARTTIME, t.ENDTIME, t.TASKID)
   .select(
       select(val(someId), val(someStartTime), val(someEndTime), val(someTaskId))
      .whereNotExists(
           selectFrom(t)
          .where( val(someStartTime).between(t.STARTTIME).and(t.ENDTIME)
              .or(val(someEndTime).between(t.STARTTIME).and(t.ENDTIME)) )
          .and(val(someTaskId).eq(t.TASKID))
       )
   )
   .execute();
```

The above is, as always, assuming the following static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: Is it possible to select all values of a record instead of selecting each value separately? I want to do something like `.select(select(record).whereNotExists(...`

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: That's an interesting thought. You could write the glue code, of course, or you use the `VALUES()` table constructor: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/values. E.g. `selectFrom(values(record.fieldsRow()))`. Would you mind asking that as a new, separate question? Then I can explain more in detail and future visitors will also see it.

Comment: Using the `VALUES()` table constructor is working fine. I created a separate question anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52538400/6172447