# Is it possible to select all values of a record instead of having to select each value separately?

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, jooq

I need to select all the values of a record. 
I learned that it´s possible to select each value of the record separately using the `DSL.val()` function.
Let´s say we have a record `R` with the following properties:
`name: String`, `number: Int`. Selecting each value of the record separately would look like this:

```
R myRecord = new R()
ctx.select(val(myRecord.name), val(myRecord.number))
```

As you can guess this will get pretty tedious when you have a record with 15 properties.

**Is it possible to select all values of a record instead of having to select each value separately?**

I imagine something like this:

```
ctx.select(myRecord)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the type safety, then you can use [`Record.valuesRow()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#valuesRow--).[`fields()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Row.html#fields--):

```
ctx.select(myRecord.valuesRow().fields());
```

This will produce a `Select<Record>`, whose number of columns is unknown to the compiler. If you prefer profiting from the additional type safety provided by your specific `R` record type (I'm assuming e.g. `Record2<String, Integer>`), then you can use the [`values()` constructor](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/values):

```
ctx.selectFrom(values(myRecord.valuesRow()));
```